# Не получается при продаже товара, списывать, остаток с базы данных

Tags: mvc, entity-framework-core

```
        {
            if(id==null)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            ViewBag.Rez = id;

            return View();

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string  Buy(Order order, Phone phone)
        {
            db.Orders.Add(order);
             db.SaveChanges();
            phone.Count--;
            db.Phones.Update(phone);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return "Спасибо, " + order.User + ", за покупку!";
    


        }
```

Есть класс Phone,который имеет  свойство Count(остаток товара), но при продаже остаток не меняется.
Или надо создать третью переменную, для сохранения данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все проще.
Допустим

```
public class Phone 
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
}
    
    [HttpPost]
public string  Buy(Order order, Phone phone)
{
        db.Orders.Add(order);
        // Обновляем объект базы. Phones - имя таблицы для Phone
        var phoneInDb = db.Phones.Where(con => con.ID == phone.ID).FirstOrDefault();
        phoneInDb.Count = phoneInDb.Count - 1;
        db.Phones.Update(phoneInDb);
        // Не рекомендуется в одном методе использовать больше одного SaveChanges.
        db.SaveChanges();
    
        return "Спасибо, " + order.User + ", за покупку!";
}
```

Comment: При написании кода вышла вот такая ошибка.      Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'MobileContext' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'MobileContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Хотя директория LINQ подключено.

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, допустил описку. db.Phones.Where(...)
Название таблицы, которая установлена в контексте для сущности Phone

Comment: Также можно добавить проверку, что phoneInDb вообще найден, так как FirsOrDefault() может вернуть null. И также я предполагал, что Phone phone содержит ID базы, если нет, то в условии where необходимо написать условие для поиска объекта базы.

Comment: И в функцию лучше отправлять только PhoneId, весь объект там не нужен, используется только Id.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все заработало.

Comment: Ответ можно принять, тогда я получу лучик добра))

Comment: Не могу понять, как отметить , что ответ дан и указать тебя, подскажешь, буду признателен

Comment: В левом верхнем углу сообщения есть стрелочки, для возможности отдачи голоса за ответ. Голосование за является бесплатным, голосование против отнимает очки репутации. Чуть ниже них серая галочка для принятия ответа. Ревомендую ознакомиться с вводной инструкцией, довольно интересная система)